# Does Éomer of the Riddermark trigger if there are two creatures with equal power?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Card in question: [Éomer of the Riddermark](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=%C3%89omer%20of%20the%20Riddermark)

> Whenever Éomer of the Riddermark attacks, if you control a creature with the greatest power among creatures on the battlefield, create a 1/1 white Human Soldier creature token.

If you and opponent both control a creature with equal power, does this ability trigger? I'd have expected this to be in a ruling, but surprisingly, there is no ruling on Gatherer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.
There's not really rules to back it up, besides english.

> If you control **a** creature with the greatest power...

The "a" implies there can be more than one such creature.

The text is equivalent to

> If you control a creature with power equal to the greatest power...

Comment: Hmm, looks like I was too fixated on "greatest power" being a superlative.

Comment: The "greatest power among creatures on the battlefield" is some well defined number, even if multiple creatures have that power. Then you can easily check whether you have a creature with that power.

Comment: There are cards such as Selvala, Heart of the Wilds which care about a single creature having the greatest power, but those are worded euqally unambiguously.

Comment: Interestingly, Padeem, Consul of Innovation doesn't follow the same templating.